# All three words mean same but is there any particular rule when to use which one?

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german, swiss-standard-german

Karriere, Berufslaufbahn, and Werdegang mean career.

Can we use any word alternatively or they need to be used depending on any specific context?

Answer (score 3):

**Karriere** has an implication of success, (Berufs-)laufbahn doesn't. Also, Berufslaufbahn is obviously less of a foreign word (Fremdwort) than Karriere, which might make a difference in some contexts. For example, if you're a business that tries to recruit and would like to look cool, you will probably use Karriere.

When talking about the [career paths](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laufbahn_(Dienstrecht)) of officials (Beamte), you're more likely to find **"Laufbahn"**. (In the north German city of Kiel, there is a small pedestrian path with the name "Beamtenlaufbahn" that connects the city hall with the police headquarters. The name is a pun of course.)

**Werdegang** (lit.: "path of becoming") is mostly used retrospectively. For example, it could be used in a CV or bio, to describe how a person became who they are today. Or it could be used for a description of what steps a person would need to have done to be, say, a master carpenter.